# Wordpress change directory

Tags: wordpress

I have a little problem, i wanted to install my wordpress site in my server (i changed, i've a new server and adress).

And this is what i have,

How can i change the defaut directory, if you click right you will see the sources :

I don't want to have in the beginning, abcsolar.ch etc... just nothing, or `http://85.236.158.35/~hqdoryev/`.

example : `http://85.236.158.35/~hqdoryev/`

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
    <title>Page not found | ABC Solar</title>
    <link rel="icon" href="http://www.abcsolar.ch/wp-content/themes/abcsolar/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
    <link rel="profile" href="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11">
    <link rel="pingback" href="http://www.abcsolar.ch/xmlrpc.php">
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="http://www.abcsolar.ch/wp-content/themes/abcsolar/js/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
    <meta name='robots' content='noindex,nofollow' />
<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="ABC Solar &raquo; Feed" href="http://www.abcsolar.ch/feed/" />
<link rel="alternate" type="application/rss+xml" title="ABC Solar &raquo; Comments Feed" href="http://www.abcsolar.ch/comments/feed/" />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='slider-ui-css'  href='http://www.abcsolar.ch/wp-content/plugins/thethe-image-slider/style/css/thethe-image-slider.css?ver=3.6.1' type='text/css' media='screen' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='contact-form-7-css'  href='http://www.abcsolar.ch/wp-content/plugins/contact-form-7/includes/css/styles.css?ver=3.5.2' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='twentythirteen-fonts-css'  href='//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro%3A300%2C400%2C700%2C300italic%2C400italic%2C700italic%7CBitter%3A400%2C700&#038;subset=latin%2Clatin-ext' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='genericons-css'  href='http://www.abcsolar.ch/wp-content/themes/abcsolar/fonts/genericons.css?ver=2.09' type='text/css' media='all' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='twentythirteen-style-css'  href='http://www.abcsolar.ch/wp-content/themes/abcsolar/style.css?ver=2013-07-18' type='text/css' media='all' />
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<link rel='stylesheet' id='twentythirteen-ie-css'  href='http://www.abcsolar.ch/wp-content/themes/abcsolar/css/ie.css?ver=2013-07-18' type='text/css' media='all' />
<![endif]-->
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js?ver=1.6.4'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://www.abcsolar.ch/wp-content/plugins/thethe-image-slider/style/js/thethe-image-slider.js?ver=3.6.1'></script>
<link rel="EditURI" type="application/rsd+xml" title="RSD" href="http://www.abcsolar.ch/xmlrpc.php?rsd" />
<link rel="wlwmanifest" type="application/wlwmanifest+xml" href="http://www.abcsolar.ch/wp-includes/wlwmanifest.xml" /> 
<meta name="generator" content="WordPress 3.6.1" />
    <style type="text/css">.recentcomments a{display:inline !important;padding:0 !important;margin:0 !important;}</style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
       jQuery(document).ready(function(){

          jQuery("#menu-item-117 > a").attr("href","http://www.abcsolar.ch/calculer-mes-revenus");

         });
    </script>
</head>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked through the [Moving WordPress Codex page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Moving_WordPress)?  I don't think you can strip out the domain name entirely - I'd recommend the "Search and Replace for WordPress Databases Script" mentioned on that page.  I use it frequently to copy from my production servers to dev.